# How to run multipe Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs in same session asynchronously

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rdbms, dbms-scheduler

Is it possible to run multiple dbms_scheduler jobs in same database session asynchronously?

The objective here is - Say we have two jobs JOB_1 and JOB_2 and they are modifying the same table. The data updated by JOB_1 (but not committed yet) should be available in JOB_2.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Each job always runs in its own database session; when the session ends, its work is either committed or rolled back.

If you need the task for JOB_2 to see changes updated by JOB_1 but not yet committed, it must be run in the same transaction, which means they must be run in a single job.